# Angular input auto-focus not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone

I need to focus on an input as soon as it becomes visible (AngularJS).
I used `ng-attr-autofocus` to do so.

```
<input ng-attr-autofocus="{{SOME_SCOPE_VARIABLE}}">
```

It works great, accept for IOS devices.
I realized that IOS developers "canceled" the behavior of `.focus()` function.

I can't find a way to focus, I tried adding directives and many other methods I came across to, no success. (I need to do it to make the keypad visible)

**EDIT:** PHP

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
 <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

home.html

```
   <input type="text" auto-focus>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail and explanation of what you are saying in your answer.